# How to add timeout to FLTK pop-up dialog

Tags: fltk

I am using FLTK library and have used a pop-up function `fl_input()` from `Fl_ask.h`. I want a feature that if the user doesn't input and data for 3 seconds, the function should return. How can I make this function return without pressing `OK` or `cancel`. Is there anyway to get a handle to this pop-up dialog? This is the code I'm using

```
const char *message = "Enter name here";

Fl::lock();
char *c = (char*)fl_input(message, "");
if(c == NULL)
    c = "";
Fl::unlock();
```

Comment: OK. It's not possible it seems to get a handle to this function. I will make my own dialog box. Can anyone show me an example for add_timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this easily using fl_input because there is no handle to the window.  Have a look at the fl_input source in src/fl_ask.cxx.  You will see it calls input_innards.  If you track through to input_innards, you'll see that it calls innards.  If you then follow innards, you will find a while loop which reads

```
while (message_form->shown()) Fl::wait();
```

Make a copy of fl_ask.cxx, say timed_ask.cxx.  Make all the fl_ routines static.  Change fl_input as follows:

```
const char* timed_input(double timeout, const char *fmt, const char *defstr, ...) {

  if (avoidRecursion) return 0;

  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, defstr);
  const char* r = timed_input_innards(timeout, fmt, ap, defstr, FL_NORMAL_INPUT);
  va_end(ap);
  return r;
}
```

Make a copy of input_innards and rename the new one to timed_input_innards (this keeps the other fl_routines happy unless you want to delete them).

```
static const char* timed_input_innards(double timeout, const char* fmt, va_list ap,
             const char* defstr, uchar type) {
...
int r = timed_innards(timeout, fmt, ap, fl_cancel, fl_ok, 0);
...
```

Make a copy of innards and rename the new one to timed_innards

```
static int timed_innards(double timeout, const char* fmt, va_list ap,
  const char *b0,
  const char *b1,
  const char *b2)
{
    ...
    Fl::add_timeout(timeout, hide_form, message_form);
    while (message_form->shown()) Fl::wait();
    ...
}
```

Add the timeout routine

```
void hide_form(void* data)
{
    // You could do this or use message_form directly
    Fl_Window* form = reinterpret_cast<Fl_Window*>(data);
    form->hide();
}
```

This will cause message_form->shown() to be false and exit the while loop.